# How to get string from resources strings into a fragment

Tags: android

I tried reading a number of solutions on Stack Overflow and have found they either don't work for my scenario or I simply don't understand their explanation (I am very new to Java and Android.
I have strings set up under res/values/strings.xml that I wish to use in the class:-

```
public class AttractionFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.word_list, container, false);

    // create an array list of details
    final ArrayList<Details> details = new ArrayList<>();

    // Details details
    details.add(new Details(getActivity().getString(R.string.fun_bigsplash_name), getString(R.string.fun_bigsplash_addr), R.string.fun_bigsplash_num, R.drawable.bigsplash));
```

I've tried a number of variants (the reason they are different is just to show what I tried) but can't work it out. The R.drawable.bigsplash works fine (when I'm using literal strings for the others).

The error message states an int, which I assume means it's getting the reference and not the actual string.

How do I get the string from within the fragment?

Thanks.

Comment: paste the error as well

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use:

```
getResources().getString(R.string.my_string);
```

or just:

```
getString(R.string.my_string);
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found getString worked if I first created the String variable separately, then added it to the ArrayList after. Why does that work, but when I use the getString directly in the ArrayList is does not work?

Answer (score 3):

Read String value or String Array In Java Code.

1. Define a string array in strings.xml use string-array xml element.

   Show Selection

   ```
   <string name="auto_complete_text_view_car">Input Favorite Car Name</string>

   <string-array name="car_array">
       <item>Audi</item>
       <item>BMW</item>
       <item>Benz</item>
       <item>Ford</item>
       <item>Toyota</item>
       <item>Tesla</item>
       <item>Honda</item>
       <item>Hyundai</item>
   </string-array>
   ```
2. Read String Value In Java Code. Only string name

**Inside Activity::**

```
String defaultInputText = getResources().getString(R.string.auto_complete_text_view_car);
```

**Inside Fragment::**

```
String defaultInputText = getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.auto_complete_text_view_car);
```

3. Read the string array in java source code. Please note car_array is just the string array name defined in strings.xml.

**Inside Activity::**

```
String carArr[] = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.car_array);
```

**Inside Fragment::**

```
String carArr[] = getActivity().getResources().getStringArray(R.array.car_array);
```

Answer (score 2):

Simplest way to get string from resource in any part of your code is to override Application class and create static method to obtain "Application context".

For example, check out the application class for my app AB Music.

https://github.com/amit-bhandari/AB-Music-Player/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/music/player/bhandari/m/MyApp.java

Refer method

```
public static Context getContext(){
        return instance;
}
```

Now you can  get string from resource anywhere in your code by simply calling.

```
MyApp.getContext().getString(R.string.mystring)
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

try this one

```
getActivity().getResources().getString(R.string.app_name)
```